# Can connect to Droplet only using root user

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to set up a Digital Ocean Droplet, and i have created a new user to follow best practices and also so that i can run the code command, because it isn't allowed as the root user.
I can login using
`ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@droplet_ip`
but running
`ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa my_user@droplet_ip`
returns `my_user@droplet_ip: Permission denied (publickey).`
Why is this issue occuring?
I also have managed to change the user after logging in as root using `sudo su my_user`, but when I try to run `code` it says 
 `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory` which is very odd.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: have you copied your public key to the droplet? `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@remoteDroplet`

Comment: This is what i get after running this command: ```/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/wsl_user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
user@remoteDroplet: Permission denied (publickey).``` and if i do it as root@remoteDroplet i get ```/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: WARNING: All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system.```